# Installing Nativescript: Error with Cocoapods

Tags: ios, cocoapods, nativescript

I'm trying to install Nativescript on my Mac (running OS Sierra). I'm doing exactly as the website says and I've tried to search everywhere I could to find the solution but no luck.

I get a couple deprecated warnings at the beginning but everything really starts going down the drain when it gets to Cocoapods.

Here is what goes on the terminal (sorry for posting the whole thing but maybe there are other errors that I'm not noticing):

```
Theos-MacBook-Pro:/ theobalestra$ brew install xcproj
Warning: xcproj-0.2.1 already installed
Theos-MacBook-Pro:/ theobalestra$ npm i -g nativescript
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.7: Use uuid module instead
npm WARN deprecated lodash-node@2.4.1: This package is discontinued.                 Use lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.3.3: Use uuid module instead

> nativescript@3.0.1 preuninstall /Users/theobalestra/.npm-    packages/lib/node_modules/nativescript
> node preuninstall.js

Failed to complete all pre-uninstall steps.
/Users/theobalestra/.npm-packages/bin/nativescript ->     /Users/theobalestra/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/nativescript/bin/tns
/Users/theobalestra/.npm-packages/bin/tns -> /Users/theobalestra/.npm-    packages/lib/node_modules/nativescript/bin/tns

> nativescript@3.0.1 postinstall /Users/theobalestra/.npm-    packages/lib/node_modules/nativescript
> node postinstall.js

WARNING: adb from the Android SDK is not installed or is not configured     properly.
For Android-related operations, the NativeScript CLI will use a built-in version of adb.
To avoid possible issues with the native Android emulator, Genymotion or connected
Android devices, verify that you have installed the latest Android SDK and
its dependencies as described in     http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements

TIP: To avoid setting up the necessary environment variables, you can use the Homebrew package manager to install the Android SDK and its dependencies.

Verifying CocoaPods. This may take more than a minute, please be patient.
  ◜ Installing iOS runtime.⸨░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠧ normalizeTree: sill install lo      
◠ Installing iOS runtime.⸨░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠙ normalizeTree: sill install lo  
◝ Installing iOS runtime.⸨░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠙ normalizeTree: sill install lo  
◞ Installing iOS runtime.⸨░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠙ normalizeTree: sill install lo  
◡ Installing iOS runtime.⸨░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠙ normalizeTree: sill install lo  
◟ Installing iOS runtime.⸨   ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠧ cloneCurrentTree: sill cloneCu  
◜ Installing iOS runtime.⸨    ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠙ loadRequestedDeps: sill instal  
◠ Installing iOS runtime.⸨    ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠙ loadRequestedDeps: sill instal      
◝ Installing iOS runtime.⸨    ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠙ loadRequestedDeps: sill instal  
◞ Installing iOS runtime.⸨    ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠙ loadRequestedDeps: sill instal  
◡ Installing iOS runtime.⸨    ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠙ loadRequestedDeps: sill instal  
◟ Installing iOS runtime.⸨    ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠙ loadRequestedDeps: sill instal  
◜ Installing iOS runtime.⸨    ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠙ loadRequestedDeps: sill instal  
◠ Installing iOS runtime.⸨    ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠙ loadRequestedDeps: sill instal  
◝ Installing iOS runtime.⸨    ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠙ loadRequestedDeps: sill instal  
◞ Installing iOS runtime.⸨    ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠙ loadRequestedDeps: sill instal  
◡ Installing iOS runtime.⸨    ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠙ loadRequestedDeps: sill instal  
◟ Installing iOS runtime.⸨             ░░░░░⸩ ⠧ extract:tns-ios: sill doParall  
◜ Installing iOS runtime.⸨             ░░░░░⸩ ⠇ extract:tns-ios: sill doParall  
◠ Installing iOS runtime.⸨             ░░░░░⸩ ⠇ extract:tns-ios: sill doParall  
◝ Installing iOS runtime.⸨             ░░░░░⸩ ⠇ extract:tns-ios: sill doParall  
◞ Installing iOS runtime.⸨             ░░░░░⸩ ⠇ extract:tns-ios: sill doParall  
◡ Installing iOS runtime.⸨             ░░░░░⸩ ⠦ extract:tns-ios: sill doParall  
◟ Installing iOS runtime.⸨             ░░░░░⸩ ⠏ extract:tns-ios: sill doParall  
◜ Installing iOS runtime.⸨             ░░░░░⸩ ⠇ extract:tns-ios: sill doParall  
◠ Installing iOS runtime.⸨             ░░░░░⸩ ⠇ extract:tns-ios: sill doParall  
◝ Installing iOS runtime.⸨             ░░░░░⸩ ⠇ extract:tns-ios: sill doParall  
◞ Installing iOS runtime.⸨             ░░░░░⸩ ⠇ extract:tns-ios: sill doParall  
◡ Installing iOS runtime.⸨             ░░░░░⸩ ⠇ extract:tns-ios: sill doParall  
◟ Installing iOS runtime.⸨             ░░░░░⸩ ⠇ extract:tns-ios: sill doParall  
◜ Installing iOS runtime.⸨             ░░░░░⸩ ⠇ extract:tns-ios: sill doParall  
◠ Installing iOS runtime.⸨             ░░░░░⸩ ⠇ extract:tns-ios: sill doParall  
◝ Installing iOS runtime.⸨             ░░░░░⸩ ⠸ extract:tns-ios: sill doParallnativescript-check-cocoapods@0.0.1 /private/var/folders/k5/jmd4lpjs4d9g2h9g_qw5qypm0000gn/T/nativescript-check-cocoapods117414-14624-9zer4y.acgt8uayvi
└── tns-ios@3.0.0 

npm WARN nativescript-check-cocoapods@0.0.1 No description
npm WARN nativescript-check-cocoapods@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN nativescript-check-cocoapods@0.0.1 No license field.

  ◠ Verifying CocoaPods. This may take some time, please be patient..
Path must be a string. Received undefined
Failed to display command help { Error
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/theobalestra/.npm-    packages/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/errors.js:15:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/theobalestra/.npm-    packages/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/nativescript-cli.js:14:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
  name: 'Exception',
  message: 'Unknown command \'post-install-cli\'. Try \'$ tns help\'     for a full list of supported commands.',
  errorCode: 127,
  suppressCommandHelp: true }
/Users/theobalestra/.npm-packages/lib
└── nativescript@3.0.1
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Recent updates have deprecated parts of the nativescript docs macos setup steps, notably the following:

```
android update sdk --filter tools,platform-tools,android-25,build-tools-25.0.2,extra-android-m2repository,extra-google-m2repository,extra-android-support --all --no-ui
```

You can use sdkmanager --list to determine which packages are missing. At minimum you should have:

```
build-tools;25.0.2
extras;android;m2repository
extras;google;m2repository
platform-tools
platforms;android-25
tools
```

If any are missing, use sdkmanager to install them:

```
sdkmanager "extras;android;m2repository"
sdkmanager "extras;google;m2repository"
etc
```